# Team services with many small projects and single developer

Tags: azure-devops

My company has used a cloud TFS host for many years. Now the host has disappeared from the internet and a lot of code and all history has been lost. There are people working on it so it might be solved but I anyway need to fairly quickly set up new source code handling in Visual Studio Online and need some hints on how to do it.

The current solution was set up long before I started and for various reasons I am currently the only developer. It might change in the future but there will never be more than one developer for each visual studio solution.

I work with many small customer specific projects in Visual Studio (windows application, windows service, WebAPI, SSRS, SQL, Entity framework). The average size of a project is maybe 20 hours from start coding to deployment (there are a few  larger projects as well). New features and bug fixes are sometimes added after deployment (can be years later) but that is usually 2-6 hour projects.

The current process has one TFS project per customer and each contain at most a handful Visual Studio solutions. There are no dependencies between the solutions and common code is handled with NuGet.

We had around 250 projects in the cloud and even if I so far only recovered 50 of these, the ones I had locally, we will sooner or later end up with similar numbers. Total size was in the region of 30GB (a lot comes from TFS by default checking in the nuget packages folder)

For most projects there is no need for workitems, kanban, reporting and other ALM features. Only developers will ever use visual studio online. I would like to work with a branch/pull-request/merge process. Coming from Git/Mercurial I have never felt comfortable with TFS.

So my questions are now:

1. What is a good way to structure the projects?

   - Single VSTS-project for everything
   - A VSTS-project for each customer (as today)
   - A VSTS-project per Visual Studio solution
2. What is a good way to structure the repositories?

   - One repository for everything
   - One repository per customer
   - One repository per Visual Studio solution
3. How does Visual Studio and the online portal work with hundreds of projects/repositories where 90% are not active. I usually have 3-5 instances of Visual Studio running with different solutions at any time.

I have read a lot of recommendations but they all seem to deal with long-lived projects and/or team of developers.

My main concerns are:

1. How much work it is to add a new customer or visual studio solution (happens weekly)
2. Getting started time. Sometimes an external developer is involved. It is not common but when it happens I don't want them to spend a lot of time on clone/pull (security is not an issue)
3. Standard. I want the process to follow standard/best practice as much as possible to make it easier to document for other developers. e.g. not encoding information in names of projects or forcing a folder structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest:

- Create projects from each customer. Such as you can create projects with customer name like  WebAPI, SSRS, SQL etc.
- Since a VSTS project belongs to a certain customer related. So all the repositories in the team project should related to the customer. The structure for the repositories can be: different repositories for each case/solution of a customer.

There are only two kinds of version control system hosted on VSTS/TFS: **Git** and **TFVC**. And it seems you are familiar with Git and Mercurial, so you can use Git VCS for your projects.

Git repositories hosted on VSTS works as other  remote repositories like github, bitbucket etc. it’s bare repo without working directories. So the solutions are not stored but the checksum between two versions and it stored with sha-1 value (40 char). And for most time, you work in local repo (no connect/communication with remote repo). Only when you clone/pull/push, your local git repo will communicate with remote repo.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Just so I understand you correctly, You mean one VSTS Project per customer and then a repository per VS solution. Why is that better than a single project for everything as @starain-MSFT suggests in another answer?

Comment: Two reasons for project for customer: **1.** These customer are not related with each other, and it makes you manage convenient for different requirements and features for different customers. **2.** Your projects/solutions really for large size, it will benefit to distributed. And of cause, you can accept Starain's suggestions since both of the ways can work and it's somewhat personal depended.

Comment: Marked this as answer because it is what we ended up doing. There are some challanges with multiple repositories in a team project but they are managable so far.

Comment: @adrianm: Care to elaborate on what the challenges are / were?

Answer (score 1):

Project(s) structure: Single project for everything.

Repositories structure: One repository per VS solution

Regarding VS work with these projects/solutions, you can close a solution, then open another solution (You can’t open multiple solutions at the same time in the same instance of VS), you also can just open the file in VS and edit. Regarding commit and push, you can use Git command (e.g. git commit, push)

You need to add them to VSTS when developers are involved, and they need to clone/pull source code from remote.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That is the way I have been thinking about but I am unsure how to manage maybe 500 repositories. Is it possible to add some kind of searchable metadata (e.g. customer) to a repository?

Comment: @adrianm You can group them with some categories (e.g. Service, Client, Mobile), then create many team projects per to these categories, after that, the repositories are easy to manage.

Comment: Not sure I follow you. What does "group them" refer to (repositories, team projects)? I don't see a way to categorize either of them. Also, do you now recommend a team project per solution?

Comment: @adrianm I mean group projects to reduce the repositories per to each team projects. In other words, do not just use a team project, create many team projects. You said that there windows application, windows service, WebAPI, SSRS, SQL, Entity framework, so you can create a team project to manage all windows applications, a team project to manage all web projects (e.g. WebAPI), a team project for SQL projects etc..., so a team project per to a group of solutions, not a solution.

Comment: ok, I understand, thanks. Don't think grouping per type makes any sense so it will probably be one team project per customer, as @Marina-MSFT suggested.

Comment: It's easy to manage repositories if there are too many repositories in a team project. Regarding a team project per to a customer, they aren't familar with  others, so it's hard to manage team project/repository if someone check out.